# Why not working filter escape in django 1.10

Tags: python, django

I have django 1.10.4, python 3.5.2
This is my template

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}
<div class="main">
    <div class="container">

        <h3>{{ note.title }}</h3>
        {{ note.text|escape }}

        {% autoescape off %}
            {{ note.text }}
        {% endautoescape %}

    </div>    
</div>    
{% endblock %}
```

In database i have those note.text = `'<a href="#">some_link</a>'`.

When i add filter escape `{{ note.text|escape }}` it's don't work and i see
original string from database `<a href="#">some_link</a>`
Work only with this construction `{% autoescape off %}{% endautoescape %}`.
Why?

Comment: When you say you see the original string, where do you mean? in the browser or the pages source?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/templates/builtins/#escape) says about escape filter:

> Escapes a string’s HTML. Specifically, it makes these replacements:
>
> `<` is converted to `&lt;`
>
> `>` is converted to `&gt;`

So using `escape` you just get something like this:

```
&lt;/a&gt;
```

which looks good in browser but not really an HTML.

To disable escape you need use [safe](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/templates/builtins/#safe) filter instead:

```
{{ note.text|safe }}
```